# Alterando posições específicas de um vetor, determinando valores aleatórios e iguais

Tags: python, python-2.7, arraylist

Possuo o seguinte vetor:

```
[**17, 17**, 1954, 909, **17, 17**, 411, 844, **17, 17**, 1954, 909, **17, 17**, 411, 844]
```

- Conforme observa-se, os índices [0,1]; [4,5]; [8, 9] e [12, 13] são iguais.
- Preciso atribuir um valor aleatório, **porém iguais**, nos índices [8, 9] e [12, 13].
- Como crio a lógica necessária para essa situação? e situações futuras com vetores maiores?

Por exemplo, o vetor de saída deve ficar assim:

```
[17, 17, 1954, 909, 17, 17, 411, 844, **23, 23**, 1954, 909, **23, 23**, 411, 844]
```

Comment: Você gera um único número aleatório, armazena ele na variável `meu_numero_aleatorio_para_usar_adiante` e então faz para cada índice `idx` desejado o seguinte: `vetor[idx] = meu_numero_aleatorio_para_usar_adiante`. Pode até fazer: `for idx in ( 8, 9, 12, 13 ):` e então o código de colocar o valor no índice

Comment: Serão sempre nos mesmos índices mesmo que o vetor seja maior? Se não, como definir em quais índices deverá ser feita a substituição? Quais os limites para o número aleatório?

Comment: Suas perguntas são interessantes @AndersonCarlosWoss e vou tentar explicar a lógica que estou tentando criar.

É o seguinte:

- A cada 8 posições eu atribuo, naquela posição a[i] e na seguinte a[i+1], um valor aleatório de 0 à 100. No exemplo dado, percorri o vetor nessas posições atribui o valor 23.

- A cada 12 posições eu atribuo, naquela posição a[j] e na seguinte a[j + 1], o mesmo valor atribuído nas posições a[i] e a[i +1]. 

- Essa lógica se repete até o fim do vetor.

- Não sei se fui muito claro, mas se precisar tento explicar melhor.

Comment: E sempre também será atribuído nas primeiras posições?

Comment: Exatamente @AndersonCarlosWoss.

Comment: E o que já tentou fazer? Qual foi a dificuldade?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss já consegui modificar os valores das posições a[i] e a[i + 1], mas não consigo fazer as posições a[j] e a[j + 1] ser igual aos valores das posições a[i] e a[i+1]. Não tenho como postar o código agora, pois não o tenho comigo agora.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Então, por favor, edite a pergunta adicionando todas as informações que colocou aqui nos comentários e o código que desenvolveu. Assim, a pergunta ficará mais clara e facilitará te ajudar.

Comment: Está certo @AndersonCarlosWoss, vou fazer isso mais tarde (Não estou perto do sistema) (até para ajudar pessoas no futuro).
Obrigado de qualquer forma.